# how to change the code to avoid type issues?

Tags: reactjs, zustand

friends, recently, i am learning to use zustand in my react project,
then i just get the ts demo code, and run it in vscode

but, it shows there has type issues ?

is there anyone has run the code that zustand ts demo ?

is it fixed if that is a type issue ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERkoZ.png)

```
import { create } from "zustand";
import { devtools, persist } from "zustand/middleware";
const myMiddlewares = f => devtools(persist(f, { name: "bearStore" }));
interface BearState {
  bears: number;
  increase: (by: number) => void;
}
const useBearStore = create<BearState>(
  myMiddlewares(set => ({
    bears: 0,
    increase: by => set({ bears: by }),
  })),
);
export default useBearStore;
```

[zustand](/questions/tagged/zustand)[react](/questions/tagged/react)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your increase function:

```
increase: (by: number) => set({ bears: by }),
```

You need the parenthesis and the parameter type, in order to have a correct syntax for the parameter